# Most Conservative Estimate : $p = 0.5$

Tags: statistics

Question :

> An Electronics Company has just installed a new machine that makes a
>   part that is used in clocks. The company wants to estimate the
>   proportion of these parts produced by this machine that are defective.
>   The company manager wants this estimate to be within 0.02 of the
>   population proportion for a 95% confidence level. What is the most
>   conservative estimate of the sample size that will limit the maximum
>   error to within 0.02 of the population proportion?
>
> **Ans :** ... For the most conservative estomate of the sample size, we
>   use $p=0.50$ and $1-p=0.50$. ...

I want to ask why $p=0.5$ is used for the most conservative estimate. When it comes to the most conservative estimate, I always use $p=0.5$ is OK?

Comment: Because, for every n, the variance of the binomial (n,p) is maximal when p=0.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variance of a binomial random variable (the number of defectives) is given by $np(1-p).$

When is this a maximum? Take the derivative with respect to $p$ and set equal to zero:

$$n-2np=0$$

$$1-2p=0$$

$$p=0.5$$

Checking the second derivative shows this is indeed the maximum. So, yes, you are OK.